# How can we turn TERMINAL itself into simple note, that we can write immediately? ( bash )

Tags: bash, function, terminal

I added

```
n() { $EDITOR ~/notes/"$*".txt } nls() { ls -c ~/notes/ | grep "$*" }
```

to ".bashrc"

but terminal answer me

```
-bash: n: command not found
```

##### reference

https://lifehacker.com/turn-your-command-line-into-a-fast-and-simple-note-taki-5592047

How can I add use terminal as note?

Answer (score 2):

If you put everything in one line, you need more semicolons

```sh
n() { $EDITOR ~/notes/"$*".txt; }; nls() { ls -c ~/notes/ | grep "$*"; }
```

Alternatively, for more readability, break up the lines

```sh
n() {
  $EDITOR ~/notes/"$*".txt
}

nls() {
  ls -c ~/notes/ | grep "$*"
}
```

---

Also, when modifying your `.bashrc`, changes will only take effect after it has been re-sourced. Either restart your terminal (which will load it again), or do it manually by entering `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
this sample needs $EDITOR to be run, do we have the way to add note without running editor?

Comment: @Por In the code, instead of using the variable `$EDITOR`, you may explicitly name your favorite editor like `/usr/bin/nano` or `/usr/bin/joe` or `/usr/bin/vim` or `/usr/bin/emacs` or probably countless others. But your solution relies on starting an editor in (or at least from) the terminal to edit your notes files. Using `$EDITOR` just facilitates you changing the one, you preferrably use by changing the varible's content. Many other tools also rely on (or at least check) this variable.

Comment: I see , it's good for me to choose these editor, thanks.